# Intune managed vs unmanaged device

Tags: ios, mdm, intune

I am working on Microsoft Intune SDK for iOS. I have below use case:
I am going to release two build one for AppStore and second one is In-House app with same code base and there is no change in app. Now my question can I add some custom flag in Intune Web Portal to differentiate two app say AppStore app is installed on unmanaged device and AppStore build is installed on managed device? Also how can I determine In-House app?

Thanks,
Devesh

Comment: If the two versions are functionally identical, wouldn't it be better to simply check for the InTune management regardless of how the app was installed? Or are you trying to detect the different versions in the InTune app inventory, in which case why not use a different bundle ID?

Comment: @Paulw11 let me explain more first I want to identify AppStore app is installed on managed and unmanaged device, so how can I do that using Intune sdk. And second thing is how can I differentiate between InHouse app and Appstore app using Intune SDK (with out bundle id)

Comment: Do you want the app on the device to be able to identify which it is or do you want to be able to query the InTune portal inventory data?

Comment: yes app should be able to differentiate

Comment: You need to change the source code in some way; You could define a value that gets compiled in to your enterprise version during build.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was looking Intune SDK files and found one more property call `isManagementEnabled` but that is always returns `false` even device is managed so do you have any idea about that?

Comment: That property tells you whether the application is managed by an InTune policy.  You can apply a management policy regardless of how the application is signed; App Store or enterprise

Comment: @Paulw11 Application managed by InTune policy means any app wrapped using Intune Wrapping Tool? I didn't got that one.